# why my res.clearCookie and req.session.destroy not clearing cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql, session-cookies

I am following bens graphql Reddit tutorial.
I have checked my variables and they are coorect
here is my graphql logout code:

```
 @Mutation(() => Boolean)
 logOut(
    @Ctx() { req, res }: MyContext
 ) {
    return new Promise(resolve => req.session.destroy(err => {
        console.log("logout is called")
        res.clearCookie(COOKIE_NAME, { domain: "localhost", path: "/", 
        expires:new Date(Date.now())})
        if (err) {
            console.log("err",err)
            return resolve(false)
        }
        resolve(true)
    }))
}
```

my clear cookie code:

```
res.clearCookie(COOKIE_NAME, { domain: "localhost", path: "/", 
httpOnly:true, sameSite:"lax"})
```

my session code :

```
app.use(
session({
  name: COOKIE_NAME,
  // store: new RedisStore({
  //   client: redisClient,
  //   disableTouch: true,
  //   disableTTL: true,
  // }),
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, //1year
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "lax", //protecting csrf
    // secure:__prod__  //cookie only works in https
    secure:__prod__
  },
  secret: "hellovikash",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `expires` in the options when clearing the cookie. And the other options must be exactly the same as you used  when you set the cookie. So if you, besides `domain` and `path`, for example also set `secure` or `httpOnly`, you also should add these when clearing the cookie.

[See Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.clearCookie).

Edit:
In your case the it would probably be:

```
res.clearCookie(COOKIE_NAME, {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "lax",
    path: "/", // default when setting session cookie
    secure:__prod__
})
```

But since you are using a session, which sets a session cookie, you could also clear the cookie by [destroying the session](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html), using:

```
req.session.destroy(error =>{
   console.log(error);
});
```

This might be the preferred way, I think.

Hope this helps.

Comment: still not working, i have edited the code, please look into it

Comment: Your options are still not the same, if I’m correct. You do not set path and domain, but they are in the clear, and you are setting secure but you don't have it in the clear. Also, I think if you are not in prod, secure will be false and httpOnly will also not been set.

Comment: so, can you please suggest what should I put in the clear cookie? please?

Comment: I added then cause those options are present in my cookie storage table